# How to differentiate between select, change, input and paste event of a datalist bounded to an input element

Tags: javascript, html-input, html-datalist

Take a look at the code below:

```html
<html>
  <head>
 <script>
 function onInput() { console.log("onInput"); }
 function onChange() { console.log("onChange"); }
 function onSelect() { console.log("onSelect"); }
 function onPaste() { console.log("onPaste"); }
 </script>
  </head>
  <body>
<input type="text" list="browsers" name="browser" oninput="onInput()" onchange="onChange()" onpaste="onPaste()">
  <datalist id="browsers">
    <option value="Internet Explorer">
    <option value="Firef">
    <option value="Firefo">
    <option value="Firefox">
    <option value="Chrome">
    <option value="Opera">
    <option value="Safari">
  </datalist>
  <input type="submit">
  </body>
</html>
```

My problem is that I cannot find out whether an user click on an item from the datalist or select it by clicking on the list or pressing the tab-key or type the whole string by hand. Is is possible to do this by input tag bounded to datalist? If not, what are the alternatives? Btw, a solution in pure javascript is preferred.

Comment: Why does it matter if the user selected the item by clicking on it or by using the keyboard? Either should make a valid selection, triggering the change event, no? If a user types in random rubbish, clicking the submit button allows you to validate a valid selection has been made as well. change event and/or validation should be plenty. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Umm... I know what you mean. but I have different functions for those events and I just what to know whether it is possible to differ between those events or not. If not, I have to look for some hacks or combine those functions or ... For example, assume that users are able to add items to the datalist. He types Firef and Bang! something is selected! although he wanted to add Firefy and add it to the datalist.

Comment: You having different functions for all those events sounds like a possible XYProblem you are trying to solve. You should not need code for all those events and some will naturally clash as one might trigger the other etc...